# No Sound on HDMI output on Acer Helios 300

Tags: nvidia, alsa, hdmi, acer

I have only Sound on the Internel Speakers and on the Phone Jack but not on the TV I attached to the HDMI Port

since it has a Intel HD and an NVIDIA Card in this Laptop it's a bit complicated, i saved the information about the System here:

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=5734e5fb06aa3a6b28c197befbad4d5109598a0a

With kind regards
Marc Landolt

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that you must install https://github.com/hhfeuer/nvhda after you installed the nvidia-384 driver.

Another strange phenomena is that if you dont attach a second screen to HDMI Port the xserver will crash about 30 seconds after you startet ubuntu.

With the proprietary 384 driver the problem is gone...